# Humans can now spit acid. How does culture change?

Tags: law, super-powers

Lets pretend for a moment that this isn't completely stupid. <strike>How do or don't the collective governing bodies of the world respond?</strike>

- Humans are completely normal except for this ability
- Limited by the amount of matter/food they have consumed.
- They can spit it about 2 feet away
- May contain saliva for identification
- Roughly equivalent to vomiting

Location: To make this more interesting, although there have been answers for US/Western Europe style cultures, lets place this in a South East Asia type culture, not as developed, and a much smaller community. In this scenario, there isn't as much of a codified law and justice system, so I changed the title to reflect that the culture may have to adjust more than the law. Is there a power shift that happens because previously marginalized members of society now have an effective means to fight against oppressors or does it simply make dominant members more effective? What advancements can be made due to certain tasks being similar? Does this result in increased prosperity or does the community descend into chaos?

Originally this was satirizing the two "Humans can fly what now" questions that got promoted onto the side bar, but people took it seriously and it got interesting.

Comment: They'd probably make it illegal, or avidly discourage it.

Comment: Welcome to the site TD.  Interesting scenario but like all laws they are specific to a jurisdiction.  The world doesn't even come close to consensus on murder, so I don't see it happening with the ability to launch real nasty spit.  Culture, government, current events, past events...these all impact the creation and current state of a legal system.  If you have questions about asking questions (we all did) please visit [help] and feel free to visit us in the [chat]

Comment: We will need acid-proof kleenex tissues :)

Comment: @ThoughtfulDragon , try to narrow this down to what you really want to know (e.g. how might criminal law be affected - when is spitting acid considered assault vs. battery vs. attempted murder)?  How might future laws differ from existing ones?  There have been cases of people throwing acid on other people, there might be useful case histories already on the books.

Comment: @Jim2B Thats a good point.  One other comment, if you would like to reopen this question you should probably narrow it down to a single location and provide some reference framework (the culture etc stuff I mentioned above)

Comment: Acid attacks (aka acid throwing or vitriolage) has its own Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_throwing

Comment: @Jim2B Adjusted the question to be specifically about where there is not much of an existing law, and changed it so that it was more about how society changed. Is this sufficient to remove the hold?

Answer (score 4):

No new laws are needed. Existing assault and self-defense laws apply normally.

There are also already precedents for this: Throwing (sulphuric) acid at a person is a well-known way to avenge some wrongs in many non-western cultures, causing horrific burns and scarring.

The major change is that since people have this at their disposal at all times, there will be many more cases involving this kind of assault and self-defense.

Given the seriousness of the injuries, a lot may hinge on whether self-defense can be proven in these cases. It'd be walk free or go to (acid-proof) jail for many years.

There is one new law I could see being introduced through either case law or a bill, though it would be more of a clarification than covering any new ground, so not strictly needed. It would state that failure to render aid to the victim of one's acid strike automatically makes it count as premeditated. If the acid is strong enough to kill someone, it would count as murder.

Note: I've focused on assault, but all this goes for vandalism/property damage just as well.

Comment: +1.  It has never been necessary to specify that it is illegal to harm people with baseball bats, hockey sticks, brooms, ski poles, canoe paddles, jai alai sticks, lacrosse nets, electrical conduit, branches that fell out of trees, ax handles, ....  It is entirely sufficient to ban assault.  Full stop.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the answer claiming that no new laws would be needed.

In terms of healthy adults in normal conditions existing laws are going to be perfectly adequate but that's not all there is.

The problem is people who lack culpability.

Every infant, toddler, child and committed mental patient has just been given a highly potent weapon that cannot be taken away easily.

Every school yard fight can now turn deadly. Every temper-tantrum has the potential to create an orphan since now those toddlers can do more than just scream and hit ineffectually at their parents' legs.

Any care-givers working with anyone without capacity to fully control their actions suddenly needs far more significant workplace safety equipment.

There's going to be a whole raft of new workplace safety laws.

There's going to need to be some way to control the ability in children or in schools.  Particularly schools caring for children under 5 are going to need some kind of legal protection that takes into account the fact that care-givers literally have no way to prevent their charges from killing each other by accident, short of isolating children in cells.

Home schooling is going to become far more popular in this world...

Comment: Agreeing with you. My guess is education will include first aid for acid burn for very young pupils, and carrying a medkit at all time should be mandatory for anyone working with kids.

Comment: *"In terms of healthy adults in normal conditions existing laws are going to be perfectly adequate but that's not all there is."* But that latter doesn't affect what new laws are created, does it?

Comment: Including acid-binders (Antacid) in children's diets would fix this, without any laws needed. Failing to give a child the supplements would be much the same as leaving a loaded gun lying around.